# Why is email hosting so expensive?

Tags: email, hosting

How come email hosting is so expensive, prices are about 2dlls per mailbox while you can get a webhosting plan with unlimited email for 6dlls a month.

I need 200 mailboxes with reliable service, is there something in the middle? 
6dlls WebHosting vs
400dlls Email Hosting

Comment: You get what you pay for. Also, this doesn't belong here.

Comment: $2/mailbox. That's ridiculously cheap. $5-15/mailbox is more typical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expense comes from features.
A simple POP3 or IMAP mail store with no spam filtering, no backups, no redundancy and no support is cheap to set up, and can be sold cheaply.
An enterprise-grade Exchange environment with extensive spam filtering, nightly backups, compliance archiving, fault-tolerance/redundancy and excellent support by competent technicians is hugely expensive to build and maintain, and comes at a commensurately higher cost to the end user.

If you need a "middle ground" I believe Google still offers [a commercial version of gmail](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index.html) as part of Google Apps for Business.  I'm not sure if it's within your budget, but it's a great option much closer to the second scenario than the first and it comes at a not-too-horrifying price point...

Comment: I would pay more for it to not be Exchange.

Comment: Exchange is great. If I'm not required to admin its busted hoopty-riffic ass.

Comment: It's great, as long as you don't care about it munging your SMTP headers.